# How to change fancybox border color

Tags: css, fancybox

I've been trying to change fancybox's border color from white.  I've succeeded in targeting every part of fancybox except the border. How can I change the color of the fancybox **border**?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're using 1.3.4, the border is in `#fancybox-content` css rule. A quick firebug or devtools inspect will tell you that.

**UPDATE** [March 2015] for both versions:

For Fancybox v1.3.4

```
<style type="text/css">
#fancybox-content {
 border-color: #FF0000 !important; /* or whatever */
}
</style>
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dqx8oje9/)**

For Fancybox v2.**0**.x

```
<style type="text/css">
.fancybox-outer {
 background-color: #FF0000; /* or whatever */
}
</style>
```

For Fancybox v2.**1**.x

```
<style type="text/css">
.fancybox-skin {
 background-color: #FF0000 !important; /* or whatever */
}
</style>
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zzw1n1hd/)**

**Notice** the difference between fancybox ***v2.0.x*** and ***v2.1.x***

Comment: Actually, that's what I did, and that's the first thing I tried, with the addition of !important. On my site, at least, that rule changes all the content BUT the border. And yes, I'm using 1.3.4. Any other ideas?

Comment: @elclanrs: I have decided to deleted my answer and edit yours and add the code for version 2.x.

Comment: @elclanrs Changing border-radius on content is having the undesired effect of showing the square #outer div's opaque background behind it, I am using fancybox 1.3.4 and setting #outer instead is doing the trick for me.

Comment: It was the background on fancybox-skin class that did the trick. Fancybox version 2.1.4 .fancybox-skin { background: #1a2855;}

Answer (score 4):

Using fancybox 2.x, the thing that worked for me was:

```
<style type="text/css">
.fancybox-skin {
 background-color: #FF0000; /* or whatever */
}
</style>
```

This seems to set the color of the frame, the width of which is set through the "padding" parameter to the $(".fancybox").fancybox(...) init function.

Comment: thanks, this worked for me using latest fancybox2 build (as of 6/14/2013)

Comment: This is the correct route as of today, fancyBox v2.1.5

Answer (score 3):

Change the `border-color` property, not the background-color. That's what I had to do.

Comment: For those who voted this down, my comment about having some coffee was directed at myself, and as such could be considered self-deprecating in a (hopefully) humorous way. At least, that's the way I intended it to come across. Is humor not tolerated here?

Comment: I guess voting down could be humorous too  ;)

Answer (score 0):

But if you want a "real border": In your...

$('.fancybox').fancybox({

...set `padding : 0,`

...and in your css:

```
.fancybox-outer, .fancybox-inner {position: relative;}
```

...add, e.g. `border:1px solid #f00;`